# Difference between while loops in matlab and c++

Tags: c++, matlab

After playing around with Matlab for some time, I could not help but notice that while loops seem to be executed differently than in c++. For this bit of Matlab code, for example,

```
>> i=1;
>> while i>=1 && i<10
fprintf('%i')
i=i+2
end
```

the computer insists on returning the string 3,5,7,9,11. On the other hand, the same program in c++

```
int i=1;

while (i>=1  && i<10)
{
    cout << i <<endl;
    i=i+2;
}
```

gives the string 1,3,5,7,9. Are the two languages indeed different in this respect or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Your Matlab code is not correct. Your `fprintf` prints nothing because you did not specified the variable to print as parameter. Moreover, `i=i+2` without terminating with ';' will print the result of the operation. So, the C++ and the matlab code you provided are indeed **not the same**

Comment: Moreover, your condition `i>=1` is always true in your case so you can remove it.

Answer (score 6):

Your matlab code is not right:

- `fprintf(%i)` is printing nothing, cause you tell `fprintf` that you want to print an int (`%i`), but you gave nothing to print.
- and `i=i+2` display the result (which you don't want).

The corrected matlab code should be:

```matlab
i=1;
while i>=1 && i<10
    % display i
    fprintf('%d', i)

    % compute next i without displaying it (notice the `;`)
    i=i+2;
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You're just getting lucky with your matlab code

> ```
> i=1;
> while i>=1 && i<10
> fprintf('%i')
> i=i+2
> end
> ```

In the above, the `fprintf()` does nothing (since there is no argument corresponding to the `%i` format).  Then, since there is no semi-colon on the `i=i+2`, matlab outputs the new result of `i` on every loop iteration.

If you remove the `fprintf()` the code will still produce the same output.

To make the `fprintf()` actually do the output, change the code to

```
i=1;
while i>=1 && i<10
i=i+2;
fprintf('%i', i);
end
```

Note that I have used semi-colons to stop matlab from printing results independently of the `fprintf()`.

Your C++ code

```
int i=1;

while (i>=1  && i<10)
{
    cout << i <<endl;
    i=i+2;
}
```

is printing the value of `i` and THEN adding two to it.

To make it produce the same output as the (corrected) matlab above, swap the two statements in the loop

```
int i=1;

while (i>=1  && i<10)
{
    i = i+2;
    cout << i <<endl;
}
```

Comment: Why inverting the order of the printing statement and the operation ? I can be wrong but I don't think the OP wanted to print the result of the operation `i = i+2` (this is just the increment).

Comment: @Fareanor - The question was asking why some matlab ocde produced different output than some C++ code.    There was no comment about which was the desired behaviour, so I focused on explaining the differences and on (one option) for getting the two samples producing the same output.

Comment: I see, good answer though :)

Answer (score 1):

The output you are telling is not by the fprintf statement. fprintf() prints arrays of characters to the screen. It is similar to the C language printf() function. And the output 3,5,7,9,11 are because of the missing semi-colon after the statement i=i+2.

If you correct the code as

```
i=1;
while i>=1 && i<10
     fprintf ('%d', i);
     i = i + 2;
end
```

This would work as you expected.
Hope this helps, Thanks